# Why upgrading my kubuntu 22.04 got the public key is not available error?

Tags: apt, updates

I want to upgrade my kubuntu 22.04 and got an error :

```
 sudo -s
[sudo] password for master:
root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/WebsocketLaravel10# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [3 589 B]
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease [48,8 kB]
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x jammy InRelease
Get:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages [16,9 kB]
Hit:6 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages [16,8 kB]
Get:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages [16,8 kB]
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 InRelease
Get:10 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease [20,2 kB]
Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release
Hit:13 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Err:10 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I searched in net and find the next link

```
https://itsfoss.community/t/how-to-fix-apt-update-after-to-upgrade-the-mysql-list-file/11546
```

with salvation of the issue:

I run the proposed command with output :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.pUgoRKwHv6/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C
gpg: key B7B3B788A8D3785C: "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

But runnig the update command I git the same error:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x jammy InRelease
Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease [48,8 kB]
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 InRelease
Hit:7 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease [20,2 kB]
Hit:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release
Err:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
Hit:11 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How to fix it ?